# Fetching client secret id from azure key vault in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I have the client id, tenant id, and endpoint URL for an application.  I need to fetch the client's secret id from the azure key vault for authorization purposes in JMeter. I have found a custom JMeter function **GetSecret** can retrieve the secret value.

Can someone please tell me how to use that function in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to install the custom plugin

1. Download jmeter-plugins-azure-load-testing-stub-x.x.x.jar from [here](https://github.com/pnopjp/jmeter-plugins/releases/) and drop the .jar under [/lib/ext folder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Once done you should be able to use __GetSecret() function just like any other [JMeter Function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions), i.e. here is the screenshot of the [Functions Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper)

   [image]